# Android: XML Parsing via URL

Tags: android, json, xml-parsing, android-listview

I have been working on some `JSON` and `XML` parsing via URL. The URL which I'm using gives `JSONObject` and inside that I have `XML`.

Here is my code what I have been doing for this:

```
HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(
                "URL for getting results");
        ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        // get xml string form jsonObject
        String str_xml = json.getString("output");

        // now convert str_xml to xml document for xml parsing
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
        inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(str_xml));
        Document doc = db.parse(inStream); // <<< getting xml Document here
```

Here is the `JSONObject` from which I'm getting `XML`:

```
{
"output": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Results>\n    <Feed prov=\"dmoz\">\n        <ResultSet id=\"webListings\" source=\"DMOZ\">\n            <Listing description=\" - A bike shop in Brisbane. Stocks mountain bikes, road bikes, and BMX bikes.\n                    \" rank=\"1\" siteHost=\"http://www.lifecycle.net.au/\" title=\"Lifecycle Bike Shop\">\n                <ClickUrl type=\"body\">http://www.lifecycle.net.au/</ClickUrl>\n            </Listing>\n            <Listing description=\" - Videos and pictures taken of both sport bikes and dirt bikes.\n                    \" rank=\"2\" siteHost=\"http://roadanddirt.com/\" title=\"Road and Dirt\">\n                <ClickUrl type=\"body\">http://roadanddirt.com/</ClickUrl>\n            </Listing>\n</Results>"
}
```

Now, I have to parse `XML` and fix them in the listview. Here is the sample `XML` which I'm getting:

```
<Results>
<Feed prov="dmoz" >
    <ResultSet id="webListings" source="DMOZ" >
        <Listing description=" - A bike shop in Brisbane. Stocks mountain bikes, road bikes, and BMX bikes. " rank="1" siteHost="http://www.lifecycle.net.au/" title="Lifecycle Bike Shop" >
            <ClickUrl type="body" >http://www.lifecycle.net.au/</ClickUrl>
        </Listing>
        <Listing description=" - Videos and pictures taken of both sport bikes and dirt bikes. " rank="2" siteHost="http://roadanddirt.com/" title="Road and Dirt" >
             <ClickUrl type="body" >http://roadanddirt.com/</ClickUrl>
        </Listing>
        <Listing description=" - Resource dedicated to pocket bike enthusiasts both in Australia and overseas. " rank="4" siteHost="http://www.pocket-bike-racing.com.au/" title="Pocket Bike Racing" >
            <ClickUrl type="body" >http://www.pocket-bike-racing.com.au/</ClickUrl>
        </Listing>
    </ResultSet>
</Feed>
</Results>
```

Can some one help me in fixing these things in the listview. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a listview, and use a list view adapter to insert the parsed XML contents into the ListView.

Comment: My query is how to parse XML, since I'm getting the whole XML in `doc` varibale as shown in the code. DO you have any idea about that?

Comment: do you  need help with getting this xml out of the JSON object too?

Comment: I'm just curious as to why anyone would embed XML into JSON. Very strange.

Comment: I have taken out XML from `JSONObject`, now just has to parse XML and fix those in the listview.

Comment: Have u tried it using SAXParser?

Comment: @Squonk I know that is strange, but right now this is just a POC kind of thing, in future server will be changed. So only `JSON` data will be there. :)

Comment: @KunalK No, not till now. How to do that? Do you have any example for that?

Comment: Use SAX Parser to parse the XML after getting it from JSON, you probably would also need a Async task to do that !                                                   Here is a link for SAX Parser : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mentioned links clearly describes with examples how to parse XML within android. After that you can just create a listViewAdapter, and insert data into a listview.

> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

This can help you with the listView:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

create a new xml file. write your xml content into it. and than start parsing that xml file using SAXParser.

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStream(xml_file));

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

dataHandler = new UIXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(dataHandler);
xr.parse(is);
```

**UIXMLHandler.java**

```
public class UIXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes atts){
        //here find the appropriate element, get it's attribute value if exist.
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
       //element ends
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
      String data = new String(ch, start, length);
      data = data.trim();
      //data is the value you are going to use.
    }
}
```

hope this may help you.